# Plesk publish asp.net mvc file or directory not found error

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, publish, plesk, plesk-onyx

my solution is work on my localhost  and ı can contact my remote db on plesk my local host its working 
ım start my solution relase mode and zip this file and upload my plesk  and under httpdoc ım unzip  my files after that ım add a new line my webconfig in system.web but my preview and my website is dont works now i try to go previer go right path http://188.121.43.19/Home/Listele its my right path ı was redirect my index page this actionview but this page return 404

```
  <system.web>
  <trust level ="Full"/>
```

[image]

what is wrong ı cant find ım try to search logs but logs looks like fine for me if you want to look logs or any file  please say which logs or file  and ı wıll publish here or somewhere and put link here.
I'm stuck at this point, and I'd appreciate it if you could help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved 
in web.config in     add this

and remove everythink in   this tags